# Apex trigger on checkbox for some records

Tags: checkbox, triggers, salesforce

I am new to salesforce. I would appreciate if someone can help me in this. 
I have an object X which has records A, B, C. I have checkbox in all these records. I know for sure, this checkbox should be selected on B and not selected on A, C. Can someone help me in achieving this?

Thanks,
KK

Comment: I want to achieve this using triggers in Apex.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. If records A, B and C are instances of Object X and X has a checkbox field you want checked only for B, then you need just to check the field for that record. You can do it by adding the field to the page layout. I don't see any programming logic here that would require triggers.

Answer (score -1):

You need a validation Rule on this field (checkbox). Read about it [here](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_about_field_validation.htm)